# Remove a custom view in dynamic CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

In **dynamic CRM 2011**,
I'm written a Javascript function to generate a custom view after a lookup field onChange. Therefore, after one change one custom view will be generate and the number of custom view will be raise.

[image]

Is there any way to **remove** a custom view which is created earlier???
I used fetchXml to get element of the custom view like the following code:

```html
function addCustomViewAndSetDefault(viewId, entityName, viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXML, fieldName) {
    var lookupControl = Xrm.Page.getControl(fieldName);
    document.getElementById(fieldName).setAttribute('disableViewPicker', "0");
    lookupControl.addCustomView(viewId, entityName, viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXML, true);
    lookupControl.setDefaultView(viewId);
}
```

Comment: Can you show code, how you are creating `custom view` ? You should not create a `custom view` dynamically, you should create the view and then filter based on requirements.

Comment: I used fetchXml to get element of the custom view and add this custom view to lookup control like the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no such method to `remove View` from `lookup field`
If you simply don't want to `add` the `View` again, you can do it the following way:
Add the line `if(Xrm.Page.getControl(arg).getDefaultView()!=viewId)` to your function, it will not add the view again and again.

```
function addCustomViewAndSetDefault(viewId, entityName, viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXML, fieldName)
 {
  var lookupControl = Xrm.Page.getControl(fieldName);
  if(lookupControl.getDefaultView()!=viewId)
  {

  document.getElementById(fieldName).setAttribute('disableViewPicker', "0");
  lookupControl.addCustomView(viewId, entityName, viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXML, true);
  lookupControl.setDefaultView(viewId);
  }
 }
```

[Xrm.Page.ui control (client-side reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266(v=crm.6).aspx#BKMK_getDefaultView)